# Spark implicit RDD conversion doesn't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have what seems to be a similar issue with [Spark sorting of delimited data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685162/spark-sorting-of-delimited-data), however the accepted solution does not resolve the issue for me.

I'm trying to apply a combineByKey on a simple RDD:

```
    package foo
    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

    object HelloTest {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
        val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
        val input = sc.textFile("/path/to/test.txt")
        val result = input.combineByKey(
          (v) => (v, 1), 
          (acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1), 
          (acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)
        ).map{ case (key, value) => (key, value._1 / value._2.toFloat) }
        result.collectAsMap().map(println(_))

           sc.stop()
         }
    }
```

I get the (unique) following error while compiling:

```
$ scalac -cp /path/to/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.2.0.jar -sourcepath src/ -d bin src/foo/HelloTest.scala

error: value combineByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
```

Interestingly the combineByKey function is not described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs but is, in the working with k/v pairs section of the [learning spark book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem seems to be that your input is un-keyed. When you read in the input from a text file it is an RDD of Strings, and for combineByKey, or any of the similar functions, to work it needs to be an RDD of key value pairs. Hope that helps and glad to see a Learning Spark reader :)

Comment: Yep that was that. Good to see an author actually answering this kind of questions!

Comment: Thanks, let me know if you run into any more issues :)